# what purpose does 'package restore' serve?

Tags: nuget

i understand that nuget's package restore downloads and 'installs' the various required packages before building a project. but i can't work out what purpose this actually serves.

as far as i can tell, the 'installation' of a package during the package restore, isn't the same as a package's actual installation - for example, if you do the following:

1. install the jQuery package (NOTE that this adds jQuery script files to your project's 'Scripts' directory)
2. delete the added jQuery script files
3. delete the 'packages' directory (steps 2 & 3 simulate the state on a build machine, or other dev's machine)
4. do a build (triggering a package restore)

at this point the build states

```
2>  Successfully installed 'jQuery 1.9.1'.
```

however, the jQuery package's script files are *NOT* added to the 'Scripts' folder, and the files are *NOT* added to the project.

this means that you have to check these files into source control anyway.

which also means that when you update this package, you have to manage adding/removing the new/old files (since different, versioned filenames are used). otherwise your 'Scripts' folder fills up with an endless history of versioned script files.

so, if you *have* to check everything in anyway, and you *have* to manually manage adding and removing files when updating, what exactly is the benefit of restoring the package on build? what purpose does this serve?

more to the point, why *doesn't* this serve the obvious purpose: automatically adding the package's files to the project?

Answer (score 0):

[Using NuGet Without Committing Packages to Source Control](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages) discusses the reason behind package restore.

Package restore means you do not have to check the **packages** folder into source control. Once enabled for your project it will download the packages and put them back into the packages folder at build time if they are missing. It will not, as you have found, add any package files to your project. In the case of jQuery all the files from the NuGet package are added to your project. Other NuGet packages however include one or more binary files.